# Cannot connect to server with external ip via socket.connect() in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm connecting to my server on the internal network. But I cannot connect to a server on an external network. The server's firewall on the external network closed. The port forwarding server was.

### Server side codes:

```
    private byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
    private List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
    private Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    public int PortNo;


    private void SetupServer()
    {
        try
        {
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PortNo));
            _serverSocket.Listen(1);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
        }
        catch(Exception hata)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hata.Message);
        }

    }

    private void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        _clientSockets.Add(socket);

        try
        {
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
        }
        catch(Exception hata)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hata.Message);
        }
    }


    private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
        byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);

        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);

        byte[] response = response = ekranGonderme();


        try
        {
            socket.BeginSend(response, 0, response.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), null);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
        }
        catch(Exception hata)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hata.Message);

        }
    }
```

### Client Side Codes:

```
private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    int portNo = 20000;   
    IPAddress[] server_ip =  Dns.GetHostAddresses(server's external ip address);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoopConnect();
        LoopSendReceive()  
    }

    private void LoopSendReceive()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ekran_iste");
            _clientSocket.Send(buffer);

            byte[] receiveBuf = new byte[999999];
            int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receiveBuf);
            byte[] data = new byte[rec];
            Array.Copy(receiveBuf, data, rec);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);

        }
        catch
        {                 
        }  
    }

    private void LoopConnect()
    {
        int attempts = 0;

        while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                _clientSocket.Connect(server_ip[0], portNo);                 
            }
            catch(SocketException)
            {        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you ping external server ip from external netrwork? and also are you sure you define port forwarding correctly? and do you'r application throw exception? and what is exception message?

Comment: It's a really bad idea to catch all SocketExceptions and just ignore them. If you can't connect to the server, the exact reason for it is detailed in the very exception that you ignore.

Comment: Thanks. Resolved the problem. The problem had been in port forwarding.